# How to add a class and title attribute to the link generated by next/previous post

Tags: functions, next-post-link, previous-post-link

The following code

```
<?php previous_post('%', '&#60;', 'no'); ?>
<?php next_post('%', '&#62; ', 'no'); ?>
```

returns these links, as it should

```
<a href="post_address/"><</a>
<a href="post_address/">></a>
```

My question is about adding a class and title attribute so that the code returns

```
<a class="normalTip" title="Previous Project" href="post_address/"><</a>
<a class="normalTip" title="Next Project" href="post_address/">></a>
```

I am using the iWR Tooltip plugin and would like to use it on the links for the post navigation.

There is probably a simple solution by adding something to the function.php file, but I have not come up with the answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`previous_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post) and [`next_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post) are deprecated. you should be using [`previous_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link) and [`next_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link). That function applies the [`{$adjacent}_post_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1405) filter. You can use that to get what you want. A very, very crude example:

```
function construct_np_attr_wpse_92086($matches) {
  if ('prev' == $matches[1]) {
    $np = 'Previous';
  } else {
    $np = 'Next';
  }
  $ret = 'rel="'.$matches[1].'" class="normalTip" ';
  if (!empty($np)) {
    $ret .= 'title="'.$np.' Project"';
  }
  return $ret;
}
function add_attr_to_np_links_wpse_92086($link) {
  return preg_replace_callback('/rel="([^"]+)"/','construct_np_attr_wpse_92086',$link);
}
add_filter('next_post_link','add_attr_to_np_links_wpse_92086');
add_filter('previous_post_link','add_attr_to_np_links_wpse_92086');
```

Comment: Very useful; worked like a charm. And thanks for the info about the depreciated next/previous_post

Comment: Glad it works, but it is crude. That is a very simple regex. Watch it carefully and tweak as needed.

Comment: I do appreciate. I've been accused of being crude, so crude code bothers me not. :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes it pretty easy to add a class to an element in the DOM. The code looks like this:

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

Pretty simple, eh? You can see more of the jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will use it in another application. I went with s_ha_dum's approach.